# Updating a iPhone SQLite DB Via JSON

Tags: iphone, sql, json

I'd like to update a SQLite DB within an iPhone app via a JSON call and I'm wondering if i'm approaching it the right way and would be keen for your feedback/input.

I was thinking of using a JSON encoded string containing x-number of dictionaries in an array.

Each dictionary would have a few properties that correspond to the CRUD function i'd like to execute within the app, as well as the data I would like updated/deleted/added - i'm thinking it might look something like this...

```
[{ "crudFunction": "INSERT", "name": "John", "city": "city1", "phone": 11111},
{ "crudFunction": "UPDATE", "name": "Andrew", "city": "city2", "phone": 22222},
{ "crudFunction": "DELETE", "name": "Matt", "city": "city3", "phone": 33333},
{ "crudFunction": "UPDATE", "name": "Mike", "city": "city4", "phone": 44444} ]
```

For the sake of keeping things simple, in the above example i'll be updating the same table.

Not having a great knowledge of Objective C - I was wondering if I could construct my SQL statement using the variables I grabbed from the above array/dictionary? Something like:

```
NSString *insertQuery = @"INSERT INTO my_table (name, city, phone){[name],[city],[phone]}";
```

or in the case of an update...

```
NSString *insertQuery = @"UPDATE my_table SET city=[city], phone=[phone] WHERE name=Mike";
```

I'm thinking that in scenario's where I would have multiple updates to make, I could create a CRUD Object (of sorts) containing (transaction related) CRUD records/variables e.g. a DELETE Object containing all the records I would like to delete from my DB, or an UPDATE Object containing all the records/values I wanted to update.

Does this all make sense? Am I going about this the right way? Or should I just put down what i'm smoking and get back to my day job?

Thanks in advance
Vortex

Comment: Have a look at CoreData as well. This will help you with this and will also handle many things that you probably haven't thought of yet!

Comment: Oh, and don't forget as well that you will need to have some way of knowing what state the data is on your app (ie which records you have deleted, inserted previously, etc) so it knows what data to get from the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sqlite3_prepare_v2` to prepare statements that you later on execute

For example

```
//Set ? for variables
const char *sql = "INSERT INTO my_table (name, city, phone){?,?,?}";
sqlite3_stmt *statement;
int returnValue = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statment, NULL);
```

then use `sqlite3_bind_text` to set values if they are text

```
sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, yourName, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 2, yourCity, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 3, yourPhone, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
```

Then use `sqlite3_step` to execute,

You could save your `statement` sql to execute it other times